# Address of the PATH key in the Windows 10 registry?

Tags: python, windows, path, registry, winreg

> What is the correct address in the Windows 10 Registry from which to get and set the PATH variable?

When I run the Python program below, none of the following three options work:

```
from winreg import *
#The following line (uncommented) gives a list of things including Environment  
keyVal = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager"  
#The following line (uncommendted) gives an empty list of results (nothing)  
#keyVal = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"  
#The following line (uncommented) gives an error message as follows: "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"  
#keyVal = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path"  
aKey = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyVal, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)  
try:  
    i = 0  
    while True:  
        asubkey = EnumKey(aKey, i)  
        print(asubkey)  
        i += 1  
except WindowsError:  
    pass
```

Windows CMD is being run as administrator when the Python code above is called.  I am running Windows CMD as an administrator in hopes of avoiding permissions issues when running the above script to access registry keys.

> **Note:**  When I type `regedit` into the Windows Start Menu, and I drill down to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` , I am able to see a properly-populated `Path` variable.  Even though the error shown above is given when I try to access this programmatically as an administrator.

---

> **2nd Note:** When I try the code at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516044/setting-windows-system-path-in-registry-via-python-winreg/38516492) per @SimonCrane 's suggestion, and call the function with `open_env_registry_key('system')` , the result is an error when `SYS_ENV_SUBPATH = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path"`, or no results at all when using `SYS_ENV_SUBPATH = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"` or `SYS_ENV_SUBPATH = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager"`,

Comment: Why do you want it from the registry when you can access environment variables through `os.environ`?

Comment: @mikewatt Because `os.environ` only changes the `PATH` temporarily while the calling script is running.  By contrast, writing to the registry is necessary in order to "permanently" modify the `PATH`.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516044/setting-windows-system-path-in-registry-via-python-winreg/38516492

Comment: @SimonCrane  I gave your link a look and I posted the results at the end of this OP.  What else do you suggest here?